# Rails 4 with You Tube

Tags: ruby-on-rails, youtube

I am trying to incorporate you tube in my rails 4 app.

I want users to be able to upload a video file which will then be posted on my you tube channel.

I am using Rails 4 with Youtube_it gem. I have been trying to follow this tutorial: http://www.sitepoint.com/youtube-rails/

My file structure has project model and a video model. The associations are:

Project.rb

```
has_one :video
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :video
```

Video.rb

```
  belongs_to :project
```

My video table has a boolean attribute called :include_video.

```
    <%= f.collection_radio_buttons :include_video, [[true, ' Yes'], [false, ' No']], :first, :last, {:item_wrapper_class => 'fixradio'}, {:class => "radio-inline create-project response-project"} %>
```

If it's true, then I want to reveal the field where users add a link to the video (attribute is called :link).

```
        <%= f.file_field :link %>
```

The video form in which I ask these questions is a partial. The partial is inside the project form which has other questions.  I also have a partial view which has the container for the you tube clip (as shown in the tutorial).

The view partial is included in my project show page as:

```
<% if @project.video.include_video? %>

          <%= render 'videos/particulars' %>
    <% end %>
```

My problem is that when I try this approach, I get an error that says:

```
undefined method `include_video?' for nil:NilClass
```

I don't understand what undefined method means in the context of the name of an attribute in my video table and I also don't understand what nil:NilClass means.

I have also tried including the video view partial by:

```
<% if @project.video.try(:include_video) %>

          <%= render 'videos/particulars' %>
    <% end %>
```

This does not give an error message but it also doesn't show the clip (and when I inspect the element in the code inspector, it isn't shown at all. I can see that the upload also hasn't saved to the db, because my console search says there are no videos.

My project controller has white labelled attributes from my video table (as does my video controller.

```
 def project_params
      params.require(:project).permit(
      video_attributes: [:include_video, :link],

   def video_params
      params[:video].permit(:include_video, :link, :project_id)
    end
```

How do I approach figuring this out?

My video.rb has:

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base

  # --------------- associations
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :program
  belongs_to :proposal
  belongs_to :profile
  belongs_to :user


  # --------------- scopes
  # --------------- validations

  YT_LINK_FORMAT = /\A.*(youtu.be\/|v\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/|watch\?v=|\&v=)([^#\&\?]*).*\z/i

  validates :link, presence: true, format: YT_LINK_FORMAT


  # --------------- class methods

  # --------------- callbacks

  before_create -> do
    uid = link.match(YT_LINK_FORMAT)
    self.uid = uid[2] if uid && uid[2]

    if self.uid.to_s.length != 11
      self.errors.add(:link, 'is invalid.')
      false
    elsif Video.where(uid: self.uid).any?
      self.errors.add(:link, 'is not unique.')
      false
    else
      get_additional_info
    end
  end

  # --------------- instance methods

  # --------------- private methods

  def get_additional_info
    begin
      client = YouTubeIt::OAuth2Client.new(dev_key: ENV['YT_developer_key'])
      video = client.video_by(uid)
      self.title = video.title
      self.duration = parse_duration(video.duration)
      self.author = video.author.name
      self.likes = video.rating.likes
    rescue
      self.title = '' ; self.duration = '00:00:00' ; self.author = '' ; self.likes = 0 ; self.dislikes = 0
    end
  end

  def parse_duration(d)
    hr = (d / 3600).floor
    min = ((d - (hr * 3600)) / 60).floor
    sec = (d - (hr * 3600) - (min * 60)).floor

    hr = '0' + hr.to_s if hr.to_i < 10
    min = '0' + min.to_s if min.to_i < 10
    sec = '0' + sec.to_s if sec.to_i < 10

    hr.to_s + ':' + min.to_s + ':' + sec.to_s
  end
end
```

My project_controller has:

```
def new
    @project = Project.new
    @project.video = Video.new
end
```

My video_controller has:

```
  def show
    respond_with(@video)
  end


 def create

    @video = Video.new(video_params)
    @video.project_id = video_params[:project_id]

  end
```

Comment: Youtube recently changed their public api, and i would suggest you to investigate this a bit, because this might be the problem actually. I also had problems with `youtube_it` gem recently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with this error:  "undefined method `include_video?' for nil:NilClass"` - it's telling you that you are calling `include_video?` on `nil`.  Which in turn tells you that the value of `@project.video` is nil, when this error occurs.  So, that's what's happening.

The next question to address is "Why does @project.video evaluate to nil?".  Your show page template runs inside the context of the Project controller's `show` action.  Has this action set a value for @project.video?

What you could do, in the page is this:

`<%= @project.video ||= Video.new %>`

This will leave it unchanged if it already exists, but if it doesn't exist it will define it.  `||=` is shorthand for "equals itself or", so the above is the equivalent of this:

`<%= @project.video = @project.video || Video.new %>`

Comment: Hi Max, thanks for the explanation and the tip. I tried adding <%= @project.video ||= Video.new %> to the show action in my project controller, but I get an error:

Failed to save the new associated video.

Comment: I think you should make a new question since this is a new problem.